# Using different data sets in the same table

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, report, tabular

I am creating a tabular and parameterised report, which should get data from two different data sets. 
This report gives learner description by faculty, grouped further by gender, ethnicity and disability.
I have got group summary for faculty and gender
e.g.:

```
faculty gender  learner
BIT             856
```

second one should be like:

```
faculty  gender ethnicity  dis ability  learner 
bit       M                              400
bit       F                              456
```

the problem I have is I'm using different dataset for summary and I have no problems while summarising it by faculty but the problem is while summarising it by gender.

As there are multiple enrolments in each faculty I'm facing problem including subtotal on the basis of gender (I am looking for unique)
as the summary fields are from dataset 2, it only allows me to include them in aggregate fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned when working with Reporting Services that only very basic queries should be handled directly from Reporting Services. If the query is just mildly difficult it is much easier to generate the data from a stored procedure that just returns the output based on the parameters you parse. Another thing is to construct a cube in Analysis Services, however, that is a totally different thing :-)

HTH,

Christian

Comment: @subahsh It would be nice if you would participate in the discussion of the question you have posed :-)